# fopen() of an URL breaks for domain names, not for numerical addresses

Tags: php, linux, ipv6

After hours of trying to debug a third-party application having trouble with fopen(), i finally discovered that

```
php -r 'echo(file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/robots.txt"));'
```

fails, but

```
php -r 'echo(file_get_contents("http://173.194.32.81/robots.txt"));'
```

Succeeds.
Note that as the webserver user, I can ping www.google.com and it resolves just fine.

I straced both executions of PHP, and they diverge like this:

For the numerical v4 URL:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("173.194
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 0 (Timeout)
...[bunch of poll/select/recvfrom]...
close(3)                                = 0
```

For the domain name:

```
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
close(3)                                 = 0
```

PHP didn't even try to do anything with that socket, it seems. Or even resolve the domain, for that matter. WTF ?

Recompiling PHP with or without ipv6 support did not seem to matter. Disabling ipv6 on this system is not desirable.

Gentoo Linux, PHP 5.3.14, currently giving a try to PHP 5.4 and see if it helps. Anyone has an idea ?

EDIT:

```
php -r 'echo gethostbyname("www.google.com");'
```

Works and yield an ipv4, while

```
php -r 'echo(file_get_contents("http://[2a00:1450:4007:803::1011]/"));'
```

Seems to return a blank result.

EDIT 2:

I didn't even notice the first time, that the v6 socket opened when the name is used is a SOCK_DGRAM. Is this PHP trying to resolve the domain name ? I tried switching my resolver from 127.0.0.1 to ::1 in resolv.conf, and it didn't help.

Comment: can you successfully do `php -r 'echo gethostbyname("www.google.com");'`

Comment: Hm, not nice... I'm not ipv6 enabled here, but what does `echo file_get_contents("http://[2a00:1450:4007:803::1011]/");` do?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I edited the post with these tests results. It is really funny that gethostbyname succeeds.

Comment: Hm, is that missing ending `;` in the ipv6 http there in the test?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use cURL instead of `fopen()`? Not every PHP deployment has `fopen()` support for URLs.

Comment: @Wrikken that was a typo in the post edit. The misplaced `;` gives a syntax error, when fixed the result is indeed blank. @David, I don't know php much and this is not my code, but I'll give curl a try.

Comment: @David Not every PHP deployment has cURL :).  (But seriously, for simple get requests, file_get_contents is much easier when enabled.)

Comment: Can you try using [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and set the [`bindto`](http://php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php) option to your local IP address.

Comment: @Leigh When I read your comment I was certain this would solve my problem, and I was wrong. Then I noticed the SOCK_DGRAM type..

Comment: php -r 'echo(file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/robots.txt"));' fails, so maybe it's a DNS problem ? have you tried to add "fast" dns servers to your config in (etc/resolv.conf) ? try out 208.67.222.222 & 208.67.220.220 from https://www.opendns.com/opendns-ip-addresses/

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV this is obviously not a DNS problem.

Comment: @b0fh you say "obviously", while you didn't even give it a try ? #http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=35549&page=1

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV yes, I do say "obviously" because both gethostbyname and ping succeed, the strace clearly shows that the problem is within php itself, and opendns won't be faster than my local caching resolver.

Comment: http://www.businesscorner.co.uk/disable-ipv6-in-curl-and-php/

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, disabling ipv6 was not acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB showed that that mysterious unused socket call actually came from libcurl. I recompiled php without libcurl and it works. I'll keep investigating the cause, but so far the workaround seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an operating system preference, not a php preference.  I think you need to edit your /etc/gai.conf file to prefer IPv4 over IPv6.  A little bit of Googling turned up [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32298/prefer-a-ipv4-dns-lookups-before-aaaaipv6-lookups) that describes how to do it.  To be honest, I'm not familiar with gai.conf, so your mileage may vary, but it looks like on most systems it will be simply uncommenting one line.

As for why you're seeing SOCK_DGRAM, if I had to guess, I'd guess it's because DNS lookups are UDP, that's probably what you're seeing in the trace, whereas in your first trace the address was likely cached so it immediately established the TCP connection (DOCK_STREAM) to the remote server.

Comment: Good suggestion; unfortunately, I tried that already, and it did not help. I also tried other URLs for hosts who do not have AAAA records, and it did not work either. As for the caching behaviour, I tried the two tests several times in different orders and it does not seem to make a difference. Very strange.